# Given known and and unknown line equation and maximising area of triangle condition.

Tags: geometry, optimization, analytic-geometry

> Q) If from a point $P\equiv(4,4)$ perpendiculars to the straight lines
>   $-3x+4y+5=0$ and $y=mx+7$ meet at $Q$ and $R$ and area of triangle
>   $PQR$ is maximum then $m=__ $ ?

First I drew the known line $-3x+4y+5=0$ and the unknown line $y=mx+7$ then I fixed the perpendicular distance from $P(4,4)$ as a fixed value $b$ .

I also know that area of a triangle $\dfrac{1}2 \times base \times height$ so to maximise this area we need $base=height$

I took $base$ as my assumed constant $b$

Then I found out $b=9/5$

Then I substituted in distance formula and I have no idea how to proceed further

$\frac{9}{5}=\frac{-4m+4+c}{\sqrt{m^{2}+1}}$

Comment: i think it is not so easy

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner but my sir told me to solve it analytically without use of much formulas

Comment: ok, do you know the Hessian normal form?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner no I'm quite knew to it but i just ran through their wiki page and most of the formulas are related to 3D geometry , this question has been asked solely from straight lines concepts.

Comment: I did some stuff on geogebra and the area seems to be maximum when $m$ approaches $\infty$.

Comment: I think this happens when the given lines are perpendicular.

Comment: $b$ is also a variable. You have to maximize $b\sin\theta$

Comment: @G-man you were right all along , much sorry .

Comment: No problem${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @G-man also could you please give me some reference links from where i can learn to use geogebra for loci problems.

Comment: The best way to learn any software is to just keep on experimenting. If you get stuck on something, there are helpful online communities and tutorials on youtube etc. I learned even Blender on my own. Geogebra is pretty self-explanatory I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropping the perpendicular from $P$ onto the given line $g: \>-3x+4y+5=0$ gives the point $Q$. We can consider $PQ$ as base of our triangle and then have to make the corresponding height as large as possible. All lines $h_m:\>y=mx+7$, $m\in{\mathbb R}$, pass through the point $Z=(0,7)$. Since $\angle(PRZ)={\pi\over2}$ the point $R$ has to lie on the Thales circle over the segment $PZ$. The center of this circle is the point $M=\bigl(2,{11\over2}\bigr)$, and its radius computes to ${5\over2}$. The optimal point $R$ is then found as follows: Draw a parallel $g'$ to $g$ through the point $M$ and intersect it with the circle. Take the better of the two points so obtained; it is the left one. Looking at the symmetries of the figure one realizes that $R=(0,4)$. This means that there is a largest triangle $PQR$ satisfying $\angle(PRZ)={\pi\over2}$, but strictly speaking $h_*:=R\vee Z$ does not belong the given family of lines $(h_m)_{m\in{\mathbb R}}$, since $h_*$ is vertical.

[image]

Comment: What is 'g' here ?

Comment: It's the name of the line with equation $-3x+4y+5=0$.

Comment: why $y=mx+7$ doesn't include verticals lines (ie: line x=0) ?

Comment: You are allowed to speak about "all lines through the point $Z$", but one of these lines is not a member of the given family $(h_m)_{m\in{\mathbb R}}$.

Comment: aah got it , thank you so much .

Answer (score 0):

First, I found the equation of lines which form the triangle.

1. $y-4=\frac{-1}{m}(x-4)$ which is the line perpendicular to $y=mx+7$ and passing through $P(4,4)$
2. $y-4=\frac{4}{3}(x-4)$ represents the line perpendicular to $3x+4y+5=0$ and passing through $P(4,4)$

Next, I need information about vertices of the triangle. One of the vertex can be obtained by solving $y-4=\frac{-1}{m}(x-4)$ and $y=mx+7$ which is
$$h=\frac{4-3m}{1+m^2}$$
and $$k=\frac{4m-3m^2}{1+m^2}+7$$

Now, area of triangle is given by $\frac{1}{2}ab\sin\theta$. It easy to observe that one of the side is fixed. (The side formed by given point and fixed line). Let that side be $a$. Now, all that remains is to maximize $b\sin\theta$ which represents the altitude of the triangle.

To get altitude of the triangle, I need to find the perpendicular distance from $(h,k)$ to side $a$.

Side $a$ is given by the line $y-4=\frac{4}{3}(x-4)$ which can be written as $$3y-4x+4=0$$
the perpendicular distance formula, $$d(m)=\frac{3k-4h+4}{\sqrt{4^2+3^2}}$$

The graph of $d(m)$ looks like this:

[image]

> So, when the lines are perpendicular, you get maximum area of triangle.
>   That is, $m=\frac{4}{3}$

Comment: The equation was $-3x+4y+5=0$

Comment: i am not getting your answer if i put -3x+...

Comment: Not sure. From the modified equations, There is no maximum

Comment: Your question is wrong. I checked my notebook.

Answer (score -1):

First of all your sentence:"I also know that area of a triangle 12base×height so to maximise this area we need base=height" is so wrong cause this triangle is under some constraints and maybe this is not possible. Second, this problem is easy but you have to write it with this hints:
Choose PQ as triangle base and find corresponding height. To find that first write equation of line PR (as a function of m) then find coordinate of point R, now find distance of R from line PQ. So you have a scaler function of m that want to be maximized. Go ahead.

Comment: Yupe i also tried to consider the triangle same way with PQ fixed as base and trying to maximise the other side , i have tried using equations of foot and finding the equation and solving and i have got the correct answer too , but my sir told that , after considering the base of the triangle the procedure was analytically doable

Comment: He said that the "the perpendicular from (4,4) to line y=mx+c satisfying maximum area condition will be passing through (0,7) ie: the y intercept of line" but I'm not able to understand it , i tried drawing a lot of diagrams

Comment: I don't understand this sentence's meaning: (was analytically doable), so he said such a line PR passing through some point, so have you calculated he is right? If you have equations what is the problem really?

Comment: I want to prove that that the line passing through the y intercept (0,7) and perpendicular to (4,4) will facilitate maximum area of triangle.( without forming line equations )